# FadeIn FadeOut Javascript tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a demo of some tabbed content and cannot understand how to fade them in and out when clicked so the content fades not the tab headers.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PtjKL/)

```
$('#tab-wrapper li:first').addClass('active');
$('#tab-body > div').hide();
$('#tab-body > div:first').show();
$('#tab-wrapper a').click(function() {
    $('#tab-wrapper li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    var activeTab = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#tab-body > div:visible').hide();
    $(activeTab).show();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say hide active tab ASAP. Then `.fadeIn()` selected tab;
`.fadeOut()` then `.fadeIn()` doesn't look good IMHO.

```
$('#tab-body > div:visible').hide();
$(activeTab).fadeIn();
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nazmoonnoor/PtjKL/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

just Use fadeIn() instead of show and fadeOut() instead of hide in your code

like

```
$('#tab-body > div:visible').fadeOut();
    $(activeTab).fadeIn();
```

Jsut check it http://jsfiddle.net/kka284556/PtjKL/2/

Comment: It fades in and out but the result is what I was getting the content jumps around, is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one->  Use `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` place of `show` and `hide`

```
$('#tab-wrapper li:first').addClass('active');
$('#tab-body > div').fadeOut();
$('#tab-body > div:first').fadeIn();
$('#tab-wrapper a').click(function() {
    $('#tab-wrapper li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    var activeTab = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#tab-body > div:visible').fadeOut();
    $(activeTab).fadeIn();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: It is fading in yet the content hops around, is there a way to alter that?

Comment: Try this one may be work `fadeOut('slow')` instead `fadeOut()`

Answer (score 0):

You can have a "traditionnal" transition by editing your code like this:

```
  $('#tab-body > div:visible').hide("slow");
  $(activeTab).show("slow");
```